# Angular + DB - Update Angular frontend when there are changes on DB

Tags: angular, angular5, responsive

I am developing a angular project for my spring boot backend service. Please help me how to implement this thing.

Backend: Spring Boot
Frontend: Angular 5
Database: MySql

Given: I have successfully created a notification when I am saving an object to my database, I just pass json to the backend api, process it, and return a message "Successful Transaction".

Problem: But how about if somebody(i mean other person using the system) saves something and after he/she successfully saves, it will also update my frontend without refreshing the page, I mean like in real time?

Use Cases: In a restaurant, a customer orders pizza, then the cashier will save an order to the system, then the system will automatically update the kitchen, what was the order. OR like a comment box in facebook when it automatically updates.

P.S. I just want to know how to implement it, like third party library must be used, if any or just snippet in implementing it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: **[Websockets](https://socket.io/)** are used for that.

Comment: You can build an API to check if there is a message for you, return them and flat them as read. then create an ajax request called by javascript `setInterval` to check the API and retrieve new messages.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it after work

Answer (score 0):

When you consider updating DB and share the result, the easiest way to implement is Firebase. This doc can help you (https://firebase.google.com/).

Sample apps : (https://github.com/firebase/examples)

Or If you want to develop from scratch without any other solutions or services. All clients should communication to each other and share their update info using socket or websocket.

Firebase is using Websocket internally as well.